# Remove duplicated custom action from welcome menu box

Tags: deployment, feature, custom-actions, duplicate, content-migration

I have created a custom action in welcome menu box like this:

`<CustomAction
       Id ="CustomMenu_UserSettings"
       GroupId="PersonalActions"
       Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
       Sequence="1000"
       Title="User Settings"
       Description="User location and department preferences"
       ImageUrl="_layouts/images/icon_contactlist.gif">
    <UrlAction Url="javascript:OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('{SiteUrl}/Pages/EdwUserSettings.aspx?IsDlg=1',RefreshOnDialogClose,500,400,'User Settings')"/>
  </CustomAction>`

and it is working fine. But the problem is :

Recently when we are migrating site pages using CMP files, we didnot set this property  : `settings.IncludeUserCustomAction = SPIncludeUserCustomAction.None;`
because of which it create duplicated custom actions.

Now even if we retract the solution from site, still these custom actions are coming. How to remove this?

I have tried :
1. `HideCustomAction` -

`<HideCustomAction Id="hideUserSettings"
                   HideActionId="CustomMenu_UserSettings"
                   GroupId="PersonalActions"
                   Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu" />`

2. [FarmAdminTool](http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/releases) from codeplex
3. Tried Powershell to see if it is hidden, its name didnot list at all :

   `Get-SPFeature -Site http://sitecollectionurl | Sort DisplayName | FT DisplayName`

Nothing helped.

Still these duplicates are coming(below snapshot).

Please suggest some ideas/links.

[image]

Comment: did you try to open the page in designer remove these links...

Comment: I believe, Welcome.ascx is from 15 hive folder. I think we cannot access this in SP Designer. Please let me know how to open this in designer.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved it!! As powershell did not help me. I have nothing left other than manually digging database.

So I have searched WSS_Content database and found those entries in `WSS_Content.dbo.CustomActions` table. Removing those fixed the issue.
We have deleted entries whose `FeatureId` is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

[image]

Not sure if this is the correct way to proceed, but it worked :)